# Inherently verses Innately

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the difference between *inherent* and *innate*?  I did a quick google but I would like a more concrete comparison and examples.

This initially came up from trying to decide on the correct description when talking about the nature of humanity (good/bad)  *inherently* good/bad verses *innately* good/bad.  I feel like *inherently* sounds better but I don't know why and need more information for the future.

Found this but it isn't quite what I want:  [Is there a subtle difference between "inherent" and "intrinsic"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3217/is-there-a-subtle-difference-between-inherent-and-intrinsic)

Comment: The dictionary definitions bear out the difference in sufficient detail. See also some usage examples.

Comment: There's quite a lot of difference.

Comment: @Kris - which one are you looking at?

Comment: I guess... maybe... `innate` seems to deal with a property/attribute in kind of a local scope while `inherent` seems to be more of a global value.........?  Innate _seems_  almost like an individual trait.... this dog is innately (by its nature) gentle.  And inherent _seems_ like it is for more basic instinct of a group... birds inherently (by nature) know to migrate.  **I could be totally wrong.**  This is why I'm asking.

Comment: Please consult a dictionary for this. *Innate* means is born with. *Inherent* means is an essential part of or is implied by.

Comment: @Drew - Okay... I did; I got confused. I can post my confusions if you want to see that...?  Does `inherent` mean, then, you are not born with it?  -> the answer answered this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Innate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/innate) has a few definitions, including one that lists it as a synonym of inherent, but the summary definition is "existing from the time a person or animal is born". In contrast, [inherent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inherent) is defined as "belonging to the basic nature of someone or something" or "involved in the constitution or essential character of something"

The connotations are very different here: to say a trait is **innate** is implying you were born with that trait, similar to saying someone is "a natural" as something. On the other hand, if you have a trait that is **inherent**, you would not be you without it; it is essential to the definition of whoever/whatever is described as having that trait.

For example, if we were to say "compassion is an **innate** trait of humanity", we are implying that all of humanity is born with compassion. If instead we say "compassion is an **inherent** trait of humanity", we are implying that being compassionate is essential to being human, and that without compassion, you don't have humanity.

Comment: this sentence did it for me... _if you have a trait that is inherent, you would not be you without it_.